# Why does (0 > v.size()-1) evaluate to false for an empty vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I am using vector to do something and find the following condition is evaluated as false,
which I could not understand.

The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   // an empty vector
   vector<int> v;

   // print 0
   printf ("size of the vector is %d \n", v.size());

   // the condition is false, why?
   if (0 > v.size()-1) {
       printf ("it should occur \n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why, oh why, are you using `printf` in C++ - Try iostream.

Comment: And, if you insist, let's prefer `#include <cstdio>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what happens when you mix signed and unsigned. `v.size()` returns a `size_type` which is an `unsigned` integer type (most likely the same as `std::size_t`, which often is a typedef for `unsigned long (long)`) , so your `v.size()-1` wraps around, since it can never be a negative number.

If you **enable warnings**, the compiler would tell you that you're mixing signed and unsigned. For GCC, `-Wall` enables the relevant warning (which is `-Wsign-compare`)

Comment: this is not because of mix sign and unsigned. Even you change 0 to 0U will not fix it. It is because of overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Because `v.size()` returns a value of an unsigned type, which means when `v.size()` is `0`, `v.size()-1` is a very large positive number.

Comment: You can't return a type.

Comment: (waiting for some smart arse to come along with his illegible MTP implementation to "return a type")

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::vector::size` returns value of `std::vector::size_type` type, which is unsigned.

```
warning: comparison of 0 > unsigned expression is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
   if (0 > v.size()-1) {
       ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `v.size()` is an unsigned type: `std::vector<int>::size_type` which is equivalent to `std::size_t`. Unsigned integers wrap around as they don't have a concept of negative values.